# Добрый день. Как отслеживать вышедших участников из канала и отправлять им сообщение через бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста. Хочу сделать так, что когда человек вышел из моего телеграм канала, ему приходило сообщение от бота с вопросом "почему вы покинули канал?" и тд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можете использовать метод `left_chat_member` ,
`content_type=['left_chat_member']`

вот здесь можете почитать описание: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat

Вот пример обработки из aiogram

```
@dp.message.handler(content_type=['left_chat_member'])
async def left_member(message: type.Message):
     await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ваше сообщение')
```

То есть сначала вы по типу контента ловите обработчиком вышедшего участника, а затем отправляете ему сообщение , в примере выше указан id пользователя `message.from_user.id` таким образом бот поймет кому нужно написать.

Comment: Аналогичным образом можно отслеживать и новых участников методом new_chat_member