# Как отслеживать удаленных участников из канала и отправлять им сообщение через бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста. Хочу сделать так, что когда человек вышел(или был изгнан) из моего телеграмм канала, ему приходило сообщение от бота "Регистрация была удалена"
Если сделать по этой [инструкции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1405685/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89) то при изгнании из канала бот будет писать не тому кого изгнали, а тому кто изгнал, как сделать так чтоб он писал только тому кто вышел или был изгнан?

```
@dp.message.handler(content_type=['left_chat_member'])
async def left_member(message: type.Message):
     await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Регистрация была удалена")
```

Вот этот код да пишет тому кто вышел, но если изгнать человека то он напишет не того кто был изгнан а тот кто удалил его.

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message.handler(content_type=['left_chat_member'])
async def left_member(message: type.Message):
     await bot.send_message(messege.left_chat_member.id, "Регистрация была удалена")
```

Вот такое простое решение данной проблемы)